# Debug Assertion Failed when using ispunct('ø')

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that handles large portions of text, and need to remove punctuation. I encountered a Debug Assertion Failed error, and isolated it to this: It occurs when testing ispunct() on non-English letters.

my test-program is now like this:

**main.c**

```
int main() {
    ispunct('ø');
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The Debug Assertion Failed window looks like this:
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eYqx.png)

All non-English letters I have tried cause this problem, including 'æ', 'ø', 'å', 'é', etc. Punctuation and English letters do not cause the problem. It's probably something very simple that I am overlooking, so I am thankful for any help!

Comment: Reading [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct) will tell you that `ispunct` requires the value to be representable as an `unsigned char`, or be EOF. It's completely system-dependent what this one is represented as.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you have any suggestion on how to implement the functionality of removing punctuality then? Currently I am using
`string word = "søme.?.thing";` `word.erase(remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(), ispunct), word.end());`

Ideally it should trim the line to "sømething", but the 'ø' makes it fail

Comment: If you're working with actual Unicode strings, then a proper Unicode library would probably be a good idea. Otherwise, `wchar_t` would at least be a quick solution.

Answer (score 2):

Character `'ø'` must be representable as an `unsigned char`, otherwise you should use type [`wchar_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) and [`std::ispunct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ispunct), for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    const wchar_t c = L'ø';

    std::locale loc("en_US.UTF-8");

    std::ispunct(c, loc);
}
```

For your problem, you can also do this:

```
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::wstring word = L"søme.?.thing";

    std::locale loc("en_US.UTF-8");

    using namespace std::placeholders;

    word.erase(std::remove_if(word.begin(), word.end(),
           std::bind(std::ispunct<wchar_t>, _1, loc)), word.end());

    std::wcout << word << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, trying this code gives me an error. It seems to be the line 'std::locale loc("en_US.UTF-8");' that causes the problem. The error message reads as follows: Unhandled exception at 0x75AC5B68 in NaiveBayesClassifier.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::runtime_error at memory location 0x00C5F870.

Comment: I'm using gcc with C++11 enabled.

Comment: @oyvind catch the exception to see the error message, but probably that locale doesn't exist on your system. You could change to `std::locale loc;` to use the default locale

Comment: utf-8 i/o on Windows compilers has some weird quirks, you have to call Windows API to set the code page and other junk like that